# Change the request of cakephp 3 using middleware

Tags: cakephp, middleware, cakephp-3.x

I am trying to implement a middleware who will read data from an API and will use it later on the controller. How can do this ? 
I have made a simple middleware where i have

```
public function __invoke(ServerRequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response, $next)
{
    $dataFromApi = curl_action....
    $request->dataFromApi = $dataFromApi;
    return next($request, $response);
}
```

Later on the controller i want to have access to these data by using

```
public function display(...$path)
{
    $this->set('dataFromApi', $this->request->dataFromAPI);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the `\Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface` API, you can store your custom data in an attribute using `ServerRequestInterface::withAttribute()`:

```
// ...
// request objects are immutable
$request = $request->withAttribute('dataFromApi', $dataFromApi);
// ...
return next($request, $response);
```

and read in your controller accordingly via `ServerRequestInterface::getAttribute()`:

```
$this->set('dataFromApi', $this->request->getAttribute('dataFromApi'));
```

See also

- **[PHP-FIG > PSR-7 > Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-7/#321-psrhttpmessageserverrequestinterface)**